# MySql query 7 days prior to say days ahead

Tags: mysql

I am trying to construct a mysql query that will pull records from a timestamp that is from 7 days from todays date and 7 days out from todays date. I can get the rows that are 7 days either way but not both and cant seem to figure out how to make this work. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try `BETWEEN`? provide your working query in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    myTimestamp >= date_add(myTimestamp , INTERVAL -7 DAY)
    AND
    myTimestamp <  date_add(myTimestamp , INTERVAL  7 DAY)
```

...should work, but it'd be easier if we could see your schema and example data.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, I was trying to combine the intervals. Should have know it was something simple like this. Thanks for your help.